# Confusion with OpenACC

Tags: fortran, openacc

In my attempts to understand OpenACC, I came across a code with the following construction:

```
program main
$!acc routine(routine1) vector
real :: a(100,100)
$!acc declare create(a(:,:))

$!acc parallel
$!acc loop seq
do i=1,100
  call routine1(a(1,i))
enddo

$!acc end parallel
end program



subroutine routine1(a)
!$acc routine vector

real::a(100),b(100)

!$acc declare create(b(:))

$!acc loop vector
do i=1,100
  ! stuff with a(i)
enddo

$!acc loop vector
do i=100,1,-1
  ! more stuff with a(i) and b(i)
enddo

end subroutine
```

Several questions:

First, vector `routine1` contains `vector` loops, but is called within an `seq` loop.  To my mind this puts a `vector` loop inside an `seq` loop, which I thought was incorrect.  I must be wrong about this, because the code runs.  But how am I wrong?

Second, all of the calling is done within a `parallel` region.  But `routine1` has two independent loops, and I thought that within a `parallel` region threads would *not* stop at the ends of loops but just keep barreling through to the next loop and that would cause all kinds of problems.  Again, the code runs and produces reasonable results, so I must be wrong about this, but how am I wrong?

Third, regarding the `declare create` in `routine1`, I thought that statement was meant for global variables that exist for the entirety of execution, not for local variables.  I thought the way to handle local variables was to set up a `data` region with the required `copyin`, `copyout`, what have you, clauses.

This seems to be a good code.  It runs with reasonable results, and was written by someone who certainly should know what he is doing.  But it violates alot of what I have read about OpenACC.  Do I need to find better material to read?

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context with these loops? I don't see a reason why the first loop inside a parallel region would ever be made sequential. This will result in all gangs spawned running it redundantly (unless the compiler saw that and decided to run just one gang, which would limit performance on some architectures). Also, what compiler have you tried this against?